# Crash in swift compiler optimized version of my function?

Tags: swift, regex, string, crash, xcode11

My app crashes since I updated to xcode 11 a week ago. The strange thing is that it works when I disable optimization for clang/llvm and swift compiler

```
let adPath = "jlaksjdlkjaldj_123456.htm"
guard let adIdRange = adPath.range(of: "\\d+\\.htm$", options: .regularExpression) else {
    return nil
}

let adId = String(adPath[adIdRange])
```

Because the index is out of range.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same issue with the optimized Command Line Tool project in Xcode 11. Can you show more context to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sorry, you need to run it on a iOS12 device (not sim)

Comment: I tried your code on my 7+ (iOS 12.3.1) and all the same. Your code worked perfectly as expected. Does the issue happen only on some specific version of iOS 12.x.x ? Or do you have something special when running your app? For example, aren't you running your code in the background thread?

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123545  may be this issue?